# Is this a bug in the process builder or I am I missing any thing

Tags: customsetting, process-builder

I noticed the following error in the Process builder which I was expecting when reffering to the custom setting the syntax should look like this $setup.Process_Builder_Settings__c.Process_xyz_Product__c but it is bringing up as $setup.Process_Builder_Settings.Process_Builder_Settings.Process_xyz_Product__c. I am I doing anything wrong or is there any bug in the process builder.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the process builder when I populate the custom setting value using the system variable button it populates the custom setting value as $setup.Process_Builder_Settings.Process_Builder_Settings.Process_xyz_Product__c.

Instead of $setup.Process_Builder_Settings__c.Process_xyz_Product__c. I dont know the exact place where this need to be raised as a ticket.

Comment: I passed this on to the Process Builder product manager.